# string.Replace not working on Unicode characters "â˜…"

Tags: c#, string

I'm trying to convert the following string:

```
â˜… Bayonet | Slaughter (Minimal Wear)
```

To simply:

```
Bayonet | Slaughter (Minimal Wear)
```

To do this I am trying to use the following: (name is the string containing the above)

```
name = name.Replace("â˜… ", "");
```

However, the string remains unchanged. I am retrieving the string using a JSON response which appears to suggest that strange text(a star symbol) is made using the following sequence:

```
\u2605
```

However, the string seems to be automatically converted to that strange string at the top of the post. So why does the name.replace function not work to replace those characters?

Answer (score 5):

It's probably an encoding problem. 
In the C# part, I'm suggesting you to try to write :

`name = name.Replace("\u2605", string.Empty);`

Rather than to hard-code the correspondant character.
.Net will take care of the \u2605 for you.

Comment: this is still not working for me.
http://steamcommunity.com/id/csgoshackbot/inventory/json/730/2/
That is the JSON response, if you search for the string I specified you should find the item. Is the "\" an escape character or something?

Comment: I'm sorry but "still not working" is a bit unclear. Is is possible your json reader tries to decode properly the string, and then later you do something on it which make it lose its encoding and converts it to something like what you have posted in your first message for example ? Of course my piece of code will work only if the string actually contains "\u2605" character, not if it has been "corrupted" meanwhile. FIY this sequence represents the unicode character 2605 : http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2605/index.htm

Comment: I have tried to use the replace function before the JSON is decoded (i.e. the raw string response) and it still has no effect. Is there a method to print the number of occurrences of a string within a string?

Comment: I ran a code to download the json and found that the raw string is actually `\\u2605`, as it escapes the backslash with it's own backslash, so just use a double backslash and the `.Replace` works perfectly.

Comment: @YoryeNathan thanks, now the part retrieved from the JSON works. However, there is also a database which (should) retrieve the same name (as it searches for it), this database returns the "â˜… " string (wrote it to a text file to check). When I run the replace on those characters it does not work. Any idea why?

Comment: Is this your database? If so, you should save the final name, with the unwanted characters removed. In any case, it should work with one of the three approaches: `.Replace("â˜…"` `.Replace("\u2605"` or `.Replace("\\u2605"`

Comment: None of them work, that's very strange. Any debugging steps you can suggest?

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear to me if the `...` is just normal text, I will assume it is. Use regex replace with all characters not wanted in the set `[â˜]` instead:

```
 Regex.Replace("â˜… Bayonet | Slaughter (Minimal Wear)", @"[â˜]", string.Empty);
```

Here is the result:

> … Bayonet | Slaughter (Minimal Wear)

Note with the actual full string I could write a better pattern match to replace in a more surgical fashion.

### Update

Since these character(s) are only at the beginning, that makes our task easier and doesn't facilitate the traversal of the whole result; speeding up the process!

Here is a pattern `^[^\{]` to use with regex replace.

It says match anything at the beginning of the string `^` with our negation set `[^ ]` that will search for **anything but** a `{` which is the start of JSON for one or more items `+`. The one or more means if there is no match, there will not be a replace; only a match at the beginning will be extracted.

```
string data = "â˜{\"success\":true,\"rgInventory\":{\"1509597855\":";

Console.WriteLine (data); // â˜{"success":true,"rgInventory":{"1509597855":

string pattern =  @"^[^{]+";

Console.WriteLine (Regex.Replace(data, pattern, string.Empty));
// {"success":true,"rgInventory":{"1509597855":
```

Comment: The full string (before its deserialized) is here: http://steamcommunity.com/id/csgoshackbot/inventory/json/730/2/
Also, the "..." is a single character which is wierd.

Comment: @JedBoffey I looked at the data, if the character is not found elsewhere in the JSON, the new pattern just looks at the beginning of the string and strips off any characters but a starting `{` which signifies JSON start.

Answer (score 0):

Since none of the solutions above work for you, it might be simpler to just cut the weird string off instead of breaking your head trying to guess the correct form.

the following way you will avoid the headache of doing it all over again if the string somehow changes:

**since we know the weird occurrence is always at the beginning of the string, so instead of guessing what character that is, we just check if its not 0-9 a-z or A-Z and trim it off...**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string name = "â˜… Bayonet | Slaughter (Minimal Wear)";
        name = fix_string(name);
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
    static string fix_string(string str)
    {
        int fix=0;
        while (fix<str.Length && (!(str[fix] > (char)48 && str[fix] < (char)57) && !(str[fix] > (char)65 && str[fix] < (char)90) && !(str[fix] > (char)97 && str[fix] < (char)122)))
        {
            fix++;
        }
        return str.Substring(fix,str.Length-fix);
    }
}
```

**PS: here is the ascii table, so you can adjust what characters to trim from the beginning of your string, and adjust the function to test the whole string if you wish later**

- judging from your string i assume you wont need more than ascii characters

[image]

Answer (score -2):

This code worked for me, perhaps you can interpret it into your code via copy paste? See if that works! Unsure completely if it's what you want, although.

```
        String str = "â˜… Bayonet | Slaughter (Minimal Wear)";
        str = str.Replace("â˜…","");
        Console.WriteLine(str);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I think possibly because my string is created with "\u2605" instead of "â˜…", but "â˜…" is what is displayed when I print/log the string. So, in my case this does not work.